restrict sts:AssumeRole to iam user accessing rds-secret to my accounts rds proxy
following setup:

rds-proxy RP and password in secret S encrypted by KMS key K
IAM-Role IPR which is used by RP to access the Secret S and key K

now I would like to restrict sts:AssumeRole on IPR to only allow the arn of RP to assume that role.
edit: it seems to work with restriction on the account:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "rds.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceAccount": [
                        "1234567891"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

but it would expect a more specific restriction to the arn of RP with SourceArn or something similar.
any ideas about that?

Typically aws:PrincipalArn which represents the IAM role associated with, and assumed by, the requester.

I can't use the RP's arn arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:1234567891:db-proxy:prx-wehrg737' for aws:PrincipalArn`. Error: Unsupported condition key for service principal.

Correct, you can't use that. The aws:PrincipalArn needs to be the ARN of the IAM role associated with the request.

ok... but how to find out which IAM-role rds-proxy is using to access initiate the requests towards?

When you create an RDS Proxy, you supply an IAM role.

Don‘t think so. I only can pass a role which will access the secret. And that is exactly the role I want to restict AssumeRole on. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.DatabaseProxy.html
